# Activity Indicator Not Showing

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a table view that gets it's data from an RSS feed.  I'm trying to get my activity indicator to show while the table view is loading in my iPad app.  It works fine on iPhone but the indicator never appears on the iPad.  Any suggestions?

```
@implementation ActionAlertsIpad
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);

loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:loadingIndicator];
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
```

In connectionDidFinishLoading:

```
[loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
```

**EDIT:  I was asked to provide more code, so here is all of the code related to this.**

```
#import "ActionAlertsIpad.h"
#import "RSSChannel.h"
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "WebViewControllerIpad.h"
// #import "CustomCellBackground.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"
#import "KFBAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ActionAlertsIpad
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
}
@synthesize webViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plain_app-background.png"];

    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:background];
    self.title = @"Action Alerts";
    loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:loadingIndicator];
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"channel"])
    {
        // If the parser saw a channel, create new instance, store in our ivar
        channel = [[RSSChannel alloc]init];

        // Give the channel object a pointer back to ourselves for later
        [channel setParentParserDelegate:self];

        // Set the parser's delegate to the channel object
        [parser setDelegate:channel];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // return 0;
    NSLog(@"channel items %d", [[channel items]count]);
    return [[channel items]count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // return nil;

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellImage.png"];

    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plain_app-background.png"];

    UIImageView *highlightedCellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    highlightedCellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HighlightedCellImage"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }
    RSSItem *item = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *pubDate = [formatter dateFromString:[item date]];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:pubDate];
    NSLog(@"Date String: %@", dateString);

    [[cell textLabel]setText:[item title]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:dateString];

    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [item date]);

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    // cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:24.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:18.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundView = image;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = highlightedCellImage;
    tableView.backgroundView = background;

    DTCustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:cell.textLabel.textColor];
    accessory.highlightedColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.accessoryView =accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (void)fetchEntries
{
    // Create a new data container for the stuff that comes back from the service
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    // Construct a URL that will ask the service for what you want -
    // note we can concatenate literal strings together on multiple lines in this way - this results in a single NSString instance
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/notifications/feed/"];

    // Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
        [self fetchEntries];
    }

    return self;
}

// This method will be called several times as the data arrives
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Add the incoming chunk of data to the container we are keeping
    // The data always comes in the correct order
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    /* We are just checking to make sure we are getting the XML
     NSString *xmlCheck = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"xmlCheck = %@", xmlCheck);*/

    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

    // Create the parser object with the data received from the web service
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];

    // Give it a delegate - ignore the warning here for now
    [parser setDelegate:self];

    //Tell it to start parsing - the document will be parsed and the delegate of NSXMLParser will get all of its delegate messages sent to it before this line finishes execution - it is blocking
    [parser parse];

    // Get rid of the XML data as we no longer need it
    xmlData = nil;

    // Reload the table.. for now, the table will be empty
    NSMutableArray *notActionAlerts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (RSSItem *object in channel.items) {
        if (!object.isActionAlert) {
            [notActionAlerts addObject:object];
        }
    }

    for (RSSItem *object in notActionAlerts) {
        [channel.items removeObject:object];
    }

    [[self tableView]reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@\n %@\n %@\n", channel, [channel title], [channel infoString]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection object, we're done with it
    connection = nil;

    // Release the xmlData object, we're done with it
    xmlData = nil;

    // Grab the description of the error object passed to us
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    // Create and show an alert view with this error displayed
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

    KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = webViewController;
    [appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;

    // Set the title of the web view controller's navigation item
    [[webViewController navigationItem]setTitle:[entry title]];
}

@end
```

Comment: You don't have any problem with your ActivityIndicator. I think your problem is, your tableview reload and Activity Indicator running on same thread. You can try this [self schedule:@selector(callFunction:) interval:1.0f];

Comment: This is working proper at  my end. I think you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: Load your rss feed using GCD Thread. i think because of loading of data you activity indicator View not show

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394752/tableviewcell-displaysincorrectly-in-ios-6/13396488#13396488